# How to create a T-SQL statement string to update a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a T-SQL statement string to update a table in a while loop.

```
WHILE @currentDayCount <= @amountOfDays
BEGIN
    SELECT @totalErros = COUNT(*) 
    FROM ErrorLog
    WHERE StatusCode = 417 
      AND Response LIKE '%' + @mensagemResponse + '%' 
      AND CAST(CreationDate AS DATE) = CAST(@dataPesquisa AS DATE)

    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE #AnaliseDeErros417 SET ' +
                CAST(FORMAT(CAST(@dataPesquisa AS DATE), 'dd/MM') AS VARCHAR(10)) +
                ' = ' + CAST(@totalErros AS VARCHAR(8)) + ' WHERE Id = ' + CAST(@contadorMensagens AS VARCHAR(1));

    EXECUTE(@SQL)

    SET @dataPesquisa = DateADD(DAY, 1, @dataPesquisa)
    SET @currentDayCount = @currentDayCount + 1;
END
```

All is working fine except the update SQL statement.

Comment: do you really have a column for each dd/MM? > wrap your code for the column name in `quotename()` e.g.: `quotename(CAST(FORMAT(CAST(@dataPesquisa AS DATE), 'dd/MM') AS VARCHAR(10)))`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a pivot table the hard way. Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

From your query

`' WHERE Id = ' + CAST(@contadorMensagens AS VARCHAR(1))`

You are updating the same row multiple times. `@contadorMensagens` should also get updated along with the `@dataPesquisa` and `@currentDayCount`. So the row which fulfils the condition `Id = ' + CAST(@contadorMensagens AS VARCHAR(1))` will only get updated in `#AnaliseDeErros417`. Also that row will contain the values from the last iteration of the while loop only. If there is no such row in `AnaliseDeErros417`, then no rows will be updated.